# JPA setParameter when dealing with "NOT IN (:param)"

Tags: java, jpa, named-query

I'm trying to set a parameter in my query, for example:

```
select * from Cars where Cars.color NOT IN (:color_params)
```

And when I'm adding the parameter in my JavaClass is like:

```
...
query.setParameter("color_params", "RED,BLUE");
...
```

And this is not working, is only working with **only one parameter**.
I've tried with `"'RED','BLUE'"`
and is not working to.

If I put my parameters in the query is working for example:

```
select * from Cars where Cars.color NOT IN ('RED','BLUE')
```

What I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You are supposed to pass a List.

```
List<String> colors = ....;
String query = "select * from Cars where Cars.color NOT IN (:color_params)";
Map<String, Object> params = new HashMap<String, Object>();
params.put("color_params", colors);
// ... execute the query with the param.
```

You could also do:

```
query.setParameter("color_params", colors);
```

---

As a general rule, it is often prefered to pass parameters to a fixed query, instead of customizing the String. The advantages could be:

1. **Reduced parsing**: JPA implementation (at least Hibernate) have a hard work parsing each query. So the parsed query goes into a cache, to be reused. If the query string is build at runtime from parameters, it might never be twice the same, so a lot of time, computing power and cache memory are lost. But if you use the same query string with different parameters, bingo : fast, low memory use, low cpu requirement.
2. **Prevent SQL injection**. This guarantee is offered if you use parameters. If you build your query string with the parameters, you have to provide yourself this guarantee ...!

Comment: KLE: from where did you get this 2 bullets ?

Comment: @Castanho The **bullet numbers 1 and 2?** Just write '1.' on a new line, preceeded by an empty line. [The numbers are calculated automatically, you can write '1.' for all of them : Wiki style]. When writing a question or answer, the right column gives you so many options... ;-)

Comment: In EclipseLink you must write list param without brackets, otherwise you will get an exception "You have attempted to set a value of type class java.util.Vector for parameter with expected type of bla.. bla..". Write this way:
"select * from Cars where Cars.color NOT IN :color_params"

Answer (score 2):

You must pass in a list of strings, not a single string. JPA doesn't parse your values, you must split them yourself.